# Windows10Phoneにおけるデータ保存方法

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

いつもお世話になっております。

表題の通りなのですがUWP（ユニバーサルアプリ）をwindows10が動作するスマートフォン上に構築しようと思っています。

そこで色々下調べをしているのですが、１.アプリケーションに関する設定、２.アプリケーションが利用するデータ、等々はどういった方式で保存するのでしょうか？

SQLiteのような物があるのかとも思い色々と調べていますが中々良い情報にヒットしません。

これがセオリーみたいな物があれば教えて頂けますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current`の`LocalSettings`や`RoamingSettings`を使います。

[ApplicationDataクラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx)